# Automating WP application directory creation (domain name passed as a variable argument)

Tags: directory, automation

This is the farthest I've get so far automating Dir creation for WordPress. How I could I further automate this in the Linux command line?

```
#!/bin/sh
domain="$1"
echo "Please save your DB user password" && read -s dbup

cd ${drt}
curl -L http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz | tar -zxv -C ${domain}/
cp ${domain}/wp-config-sample.php ${domain}/wp-config.php
sed -i "s/database_name_here/${domain}"/g ${domain}/wp-config.php
sed -i "s/username_here/${domain}/g" ${domain}/wp-config.php
sed -i "s/password_here/${dbup}/g" ${domain}/wp-config.php

chown -R ${domain}:${domain} ${domain}/* && chmod -R a-x,a=rX,u+w ${domain}/* && systemctl restart nginx.service
```

My purpose is the reduce the amount of code lines.

Comment: [`wp core download && wp core install ...`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/)?

Comment: Seems a good approach (I created backup of the WP-CLI independent version). How will you apply the `domain` `$1` argument for that? Please write an answer so many could learn from it.

Comment: To be honest I don't really understand your comment. You can use `--path` to set the directory and the other options for db credentials

Comment: Oh I already stored document root in a variable (expanded by `${drt}`). I assume the end command should generally be `cd ${drt} && sudo wp core --path example.com download && sudo wp core install  --path example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just checked the WP CLI documentation. There are 3 important steps:

1. [Download WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/download/):  (I would use it with the options `--path` and `--locale`, but those are optional)

   ```
   wp core download
   ```
2. [Create a proper wp-config.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/config/create/):

   ```
   wp config create --dbname=... --dbuser=... --dbpass=... --dbhost=...
   ```
3. [Install WordPress](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/install/):

   ```
   wp core install --url=... --title=... --admin_user=... --admin_email=...
   ```

Now there are various ways you can combine these, add your own logic and even custom modifications such as chmod. I would probably use a script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Call this script with 9 arguments:
# $1 absolute path where to install
# $2 dbname
# $3 dbuser
# $4 dbpass
# $5 dbhost
# $6 URL
# $7 site title
# $8 admin user
# $9 admin email

# download WP
wp core download --path=$1

# create wp-config.php
wp config create --path=$1 --dbname=$2 --dbuser=$3 --dbpass=$4 --dbhost=$5

# install WP
wp core install --path=$1 --url=$6 --title=$7 --admin_user=$8 --admin_email=$9

# harden security
# maybe set chmod (https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-restrict-wordpress-file-permissions/)
# maybe move wp-config.php one folder above web root (https://www.wordfence.com/learn/how-to-harden-wordpress-sites/#securing-your-database)
```

By passing the absolute path (and using it via `--path`, you can store this script on some central location and use it for installing multiple instances in different locations on the server)

Use it like so

```
./install_wp.sh /var/www/html/demo/wp demo_db demo demo_password localhost https://demo.local DemoSite demouser demo@user.com && history -c
```

I am using `&& history -c` to delete the bash history, as it contains sensitive db data. On my local machine, I got the error *sh: 1: /usr/sbin/sendmail: not found* and it printed out the admin password to stdout.

Comment: Thanks ! `wp config create --path=$1 --dbname=$1 --dbuser=$1 --dbpass=$dbUserPassword --dbhost="localhost"` Is that correct?

Comment: Are `--url`, `--title`, and `user`, obligatory?

Comment: @Arcticooling Path is supposed to be the absolute path on the server (`/var/www/...`), this is probably different from the dbname and dbuser. As for what options are needed, please [see the official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/core/install/) (short answer: yes).

Comment: Thanks kero. One last question on this. Please. No where the `database` root password is asked. I can't test right now but I assume WP-CLI will ask for it interactively during script execution. Is that correct?

Comment: @Arcticooling Te db root password is not needed, only the password of the db user (`--dbpass=...`) which will be written to wp-config.php

Comment: Oh sorry, I confused it with the SQL part of my script which is different (echoing data to MySQL). Sure, it isn't needed. I mistakenly thought WP-CLI will also create DB stack.